# Which group is 'all' in cloudfoundry-UAA?

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, cloudfoundry-uaa

owner of identity provider (SAML) will use cloudfoundry-UAA to interact with my app / resource server. i have some resources that should be visible to every user that logged in successfully. so if there is a group that every user is automatically a member of - it would let me treat all permission-related cases uniformly

so: is there any group that is added to all users automatically? even for those users that log in using SAML? is it `uaa.user`?  can we somehow distinguish users from different zones? like `zone1.uaa.user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to reliably use `openid` as an “all users” group. There should be other information in the token that will tell you what zone it was part of.